# show number of open comments on custom dashboard

Tags: comments, dashboard, count

On my custom dashboard, I want to **show the number of total new comments** (somehow like "right now"). Just like "You have ... open comments to take care of". So all I want is the total number not a list for each post or so.

But I can't get this right. Any help out there?

In the meantime I got some info (from wpmudev) on this, telling me that this is heavy stuff and not a very basic question:

> This is less basic than you might think.
>
> You need to:
>
> - Register a new meta box to the WP admin
> - Query the database for the total new comments since the currently logged in user's last visit
> - Set the visit timeout (so changing page doesn't just set them to 0 right away, that would be frustrating)
> - Write the CSS to make the display pretty
> - You'll find hints as to what to do if you examine the WordPress core in the "Right Now" widget but that's probably going to be over your head.
>
> At that point, you may as well publish it as a plugin. It's possible and as far as plugins go, it's barely intermediate, but it's still very advanced for this forum.*

#### UPDATE

This is what finally made me happy, thanks again to @toscho. It is showing the number of comments, that are waiting for moderation. It can be placed everywhere you want it to show up.

```
<?php
function t5_count_new_comments()
{
global $wpdb;

// last user access
$last_access   = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_access', TRUE );

// comment query
$where = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE comment_date > %s AND comment_approved='0'",   $last_access );
$comment_query = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT comment_ID,
    COUNT( comment_ID ) AS new_comments
    FROM {$wpdb->comments} $where",
    OBJECT
    );

if ( ! isset ( $comment_query[0]->new_comments ) )
    return 0;

return $comment_query[0]->new_comments;

}

$new_comments = t5_count_new_comments();
echo "There are $new_comments new comments.";
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it is not that hard.

- The last access time for a user is in `get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_access', TRUE )`.
- The date of each comment is in the column `comment_date`.
- Both share the same format, so we can compare them in SQL with a simple `>`.
- There is an action in the Right Now dashboard widget to show additional rows: `right_now_discussion_table_end`. See the file `wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php`.

Now let’s stick it together:

```php
<?php  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 New Comments In Right Now Dashboard
 * Description: Show the number of new comments on the Right Now dashboard
 * Plugin URI:
 * Version:     2013.03.16
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * Licence:     MIT
 * License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

add_action( 'right_now_discussion_table_end', 't5_new_comments_right_now' );

function t5_new_comments_right_now()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // last user access
    $last_access   = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_access', TRUE );

    // comment query
    $where         = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE comment_date > %s", $last_access );
    $comment_query = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT comment_ID,
            COUNT( comment_ID ) AS new_comments
            FROM {$wpdb->comments} $where",
            OBJECT
    );

    // default values
    $num  = 0;
    $text = _x(
        'New comments',
        'no new comments on dashboard right now',
        'plugin_t5_new_comments'
        );

    // overwrite default values
    if ( isset ( $comment_query[0]->new_comments ) ) {
        $num = $comment_query[0]->new_comments;
        $text = _n( 'New comment', 'New comments', $num, 'plugin_t5_new_comments' );
    }

    // prepare for display
    $num  = number_format_i18n( $num );
    $num  = "<a href='edit-comments.php'><span class='total-count'>$num</span></a>";
    $text = "<a href='edit-comments.php'>$text</a>";

    // display extra column
    printf(
        '<tr>
            <td class="b b-comments">%1$s</td>
            <td class="last t comments">%2$s</td>
        </tr>',
        $num,
        $text
    );
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

**[Download from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/toscho/5175829)**

---

In response to your comments: To get just the number of new comments a an integer, use something like this:

```
function t5_count_new_comments()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // last user access
    $last_access   = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_access', TRUE );

    // comment query
    $where         = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE comment_date > %s", $last_access );
    // to get unapproved comments only use this instead:
    // $where         = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE comment_date > %s AND comment_approved='0'", $last_access );
    $comment_query = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT comment_ID,
        COUNT( comment_ID ) AS new_comments
        FROM {$wpdb->comments} $where",
        OBJECT
        );

    if ( ! isset ( $comment_query[0]->new_comments ) )
        return 0;

    return $comment_query[0]->new_comments;
}
```

Now you can use that function in your custom code:

```
$new_comments = t5_count_new_comments();
echo "There are $new_comments new comments.";
```